# Setting TAP::Formatter::JUnit output filenames

Tags: perl, unit-testing, tap

Currently, running `prove` with `TAP::Formatter::JUnit` supports an environment variable `PERL_TEST_HARNESS_DUMP_TAP` that sets a path where a directory `t/` will be created, and for each test file `x`, new files named `x` and `x.junit.xml` are created in the directory.  I would like to be able to format the output filenames in a different way.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at TAP::Formatter::JUnit::Session says "no" - there is no way to modify it without writing your own formatter, deriving off TAP::Formatter::JUnit and overriding its open_test method to point to your own session, which would, in turn, be derived off TAP::Formatter::JUnit::Session with its dump_junit_xml overridden to do what you want - but now you're modifying the entire dump (and thus don't need to rely on that environment variable if you prefer).

I guess all that derivation *is* a way, though probably not the way you thought/were hoping.